# Backtrace less pertinent in JRuby than in MRI 1.9

Tags: ruby, debugging, jruby, ruby-1.9, backtrace

I got an issue with JRuby, the backtraces are less pertinent than 1.9.3, for example :

**In jruby-1.6.8**

```
[1] pry(main)> a = Task.create(title:"Test")
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
from /Users/salta/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/mongoid-3.0.6/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:230:in `create'
```

**In ruby-1.9.3-p194**

```
[1] pry(main)> a = Task.create(title:"Test")
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
from /Users/salta/apps/asabo/app/models/task.rb:17:in `initialize'
```

The real issue comes from `/Users/salta/apps/asabo/app/models/task.rb:17` not `/Users/salta/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/mongoid-3.0.6/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:230`

Do you know a work around or is it someting we have to cope with?

Thank You!

Using :

- Mac OS X 10.8.2
- rvm 1.16.6
- jruby-1.6.8 (1.9 Branch)
- ruby-1.9.3-p194

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend filing this as a JRuby bug if it is still present in JRuby 1.7. You can do that either at our JIRA tracker http://bugs.jruby.org or at our Github repository https://github.com/jruby/jruby .

It does look like it could be a bug to me, but we need more details.